# Codes:Hardest Code Ever

Tags: war, science, political-history, diplomacy

Which is the strongest/code that is unbreakable and exists?
I have recently been reading a book called: ***The Code Book"*** by Simon Singh and It doesn't specify what was/is the most unbreakable code ever created by mankind? (the Answer can be a code or a list of codes)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How would this be a history question? And what standards are there to determine difficulty? If these standards are mathematical/scientific, then is not the question better suited for another forum?

Comment: Are you taking about codes or encryption?

Comment: @Steve Bird, since the average person does not know the difference between a code and a cipher, and he is referring to Simon Singh's _Code Book_ which is almost entirely about ciphers we may safely assume he means either.

Answer (score 6):

Common knowledge: The [One Time Pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) is in theory unbreakable (and in practice if properly managed - [I'm looking at you Soviet Union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venona_project)).

This is a Poly-alphabetic substitution cipher with a random key (in effect infinity long).

Comment: Note that an OTP is *utter crap* if you weaken its constraints in even minor ways, and does not provide authenticity, being highly vulnerable to manipulation if the attacker knows some of the plaintext.